# Sometimes when I update the snapshots I got an Attribute __ngContext__

Tags: jestjs, jest-preset-angular

Sometimes when I update the snapshots I got an Attribute **ngContext** and for fix this problem I've to clean and install my node_modules to "fix" this issue.
I've to do this every time that I need to update a snapshot. I've already searched on multiple solutions and nothing worked.

```js
snapshotSerializers: \[

'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',

'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot',

'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',

\],
```

Can someone help me with this, please?

[Here is an image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rTBPQ.png)

I've updated the jest versions and also the jest-present-angular too but didn't work.
I just want to have a solution that does not makes me clean install the node_modules every time

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is indeed annoying especially because it tends to change after upgrading angular version. My snapshots are now failing as well because of this difference :-/.

```
-   __ngContext__={[Function LRootView]}
+   __ngContext__="0"
```

So, having look at the jest configuration, the snapshot serializers are being loaded from 'jest-preset-angular' module.

The relevant plugin here is 'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot'. Now, they are two ways what to do to get rid of `__ngContext__`.

1. replace the plugin entirely by a modified copy

Create a copy of that file in the same directory and adapt it accordingly (line https://github.com/thymikee/jest-preset-angular/blob/40b769b8eba0b82913827793b6d9fe06d41808d9/src/serializers/ng-snapshot.ts#L69):

```
const attributes = Object.keys(componentInstance).filter(key => key !== '__ngContext__');
```

Adapt the configuration:

```
  snapshotSerializers: [
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/no-ng-attributes',
    './custom-snapshot-serializer.ts',
    'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/html-comment',
  ],
```

The disadvantage of this solution is that you have to maintain the plugin although only one line has been changed.

2. replace the plugin by a wrapper (**preferred solution**)

This creates just a wrapper for the original implementation. The idea is to remove `__ngContext__` before it moves on down the plugin chain. However, the logic of the original plugin is used for the fixture serialization.

```
import type { ComponentRef, DebugNode, Type, ɵCssSelectorList } from '@angular/core';
import type { ComponentFixture } from '@angular/core/testing';
import type { Colors } from 'pretty-format';
import { test as origTest, print as origPrint } from 'jest-preset-angular/build/serializers/ng-snapshot';

/**
 * The follow interfaces are customized heavily inspired by @angular/core/core.d.ts
 */
interface ComponentDef {
  selectors: ɵCssSelectorList;
}
interface IvyComponentType extends Type<unknown> {
  ɵcmp: ComponentDef;
}
interface NgComponentRef extends ComponentRef<unknown> {
  componentType: IvyComponentType;
  _elDef: any; // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  _view: any; // eslint-disable-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
}
interface NgComponentFixture extends ComponentFixture<unknown> {
  componentRef: NgComponentRef;
  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  componentInstance: Record<string, any>;
}

/**
 * The following types haven't been exported by jest so temporarily we copy typings from 'pretty-format'
 */
interface PluginOptions {
  edgeSpacing: string;
  min: boolean;
  spacing: string;
}
type Indent = (indentSpaces: string) => string;
type Printer = (elementToSerialize: unknown) => string;

export const print = (fixture: any, print: Printer, indent: Indent, opts: PluginOptions, colors: Colors): any => {
  const componentInstance = (fixture as NgComponentFixture).componentInstance;
  const instance = { ...componentInstance };
  delete instance.__ngContext__;
  const modifiedFixture = { ...fixture, componentInstance: { ...instance } };
  return origPrint(modifiedFixture, print, indent, opts, colors);
};

// eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any, @typescript-eslint/explicit-module-boundary-types
export const test = (val: any): boolean => {
  return origTest(val);
};
```

The configuration is adapted the same way as before.